# Spring AOP Not Calling Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm new to AspectJ and after reading related issues here, I'm still stuck.

I would like to use AspectJ to log the time taken for method calls to run in specified packages.

I'm using: `spring-boot-starter-parent version 1.5.6.RELEASE`

I've included the following additional Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I've defined a Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Aspect
public class PerformanceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public PerformanceMonitorInterceptor performanceMonitorInterceptor() {
        return new PerformanceMonitorInterceptor(true);
    }

    @Bean
    public Advisor QuoteServiceImplMonitorAdvisor(PerformanceMonitorInterceptor performanceMonitorInterceptor) {
        AspectJExpressionPointcut pointcut = new AspectJExpressionPointcut();
        pointcut.setExpression("execution(* com.mycompany.*.*(..))");
        return new DefaultPointcutAdvisor(pointcut, performanceMonitorInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Here's my logback.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<property name="DEV_HOME" value="MyApplicationHome/logs" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %magenta([%thread]) %highlight(%-5level) %logger{36}.%M - %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <!-- rollover daily -->
            <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
            </fileNamePattern>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
                    class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="log4j.logger.org.springframework.aop.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor" level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </logger>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I'm not seeing any trace entries in the console and the performanceMonitorInterceptor is never called. **Any ideas please?**

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score -1):

Why is your configuration class annotated with `@Aspect`?

@Aspect should be on the bean class itself.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-at-aspectj